# When does View.onConfigurationChanged get called?

Tags: android

When does `View.onConfigurationChanged` get called?
Can it get called if `Activity` that displays it doesn't register for any `configChanges` in the `Manifest`?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is the docs from google for your question :

> Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your activity is running. Note that this will only be called if you have selected configurations you would like to handle with the configChanges attribute in your manifest. If any configuration change occurs that is not selected to be reported by that attribute, then instead of reporting it the system will stop and restart the activity (to have it launched with the new configuration).

as you see it says that it will run **only** if youd define "configChanges" in your manifest.
**[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)**

Comment: True, I wouldn't be asking this if I weren't desperate. I work with production code and our crash tool reported a crash in onConfigurationChanged (Custom view's) but the activity that displays it never registered for any

Comment: so please post your logcat and your Activity code !

Answer (score -3):

***This method is called when the screen orientation is changed. When the Screen orientation is landscape then do this , when potrait do this, you can define as shown below.***

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Remember to put them in the android manifest:**

```
<activity 
   android:configChanges=["orientation"]
   . . .
</activity>
```

Comment: I'd like to down rate this answer but I have no reputation :( .
If you pay any attention at all you could realize that this has nothing to do with what I've asked